# StreamReader path changes automatically

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have some strange problem (for me).

There is an application which is a windows form application "firstapp.exe".
There is another application which is windows form application too "launcher.exe".
And there is a console application with name "server.exe".

Both firstapp and launcher are in the same directory. In that directory there is also a "Config" folder with some other files in it.

The code which I use to read one file from config folder in firstapp:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Config\\launcher.txt");
string readed_config = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

If I run the firstapp application with launcher (using process.start) all goes fine.
When I run it with console application, which is not in the same directory as firstapp I get the "directory not found exception" from that part of code (posted above).

How can I solve the problem?
Why is console application adding its own path to another application which should run independently?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to see what directory you are in, and change it.

Comment: Wrap your `StreamReader` declaration and usage in a `using` statement and forgo the `reader.Close();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property of your Process before calling `Process.Start`.

```
string launcherPath = @"C:\SomePathToLauncher\Launcher.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = launcherPath;
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(launcherPath);
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startinfo.FileName = "firstapp.exe";
startinfo.WorkingDirectory = "pathToAfolderWithFirstApp";
startinfo.Arguments = "arguments"
Process.Start(startinfo);

Answer (score 2):

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Config\\launcher.txt");
```

**Never** use hard-coded relative file paths in your code.  It critically depends on Environment.CurrentDirectory and that's *way* too unpredictable.  External code can kill you as you found out.  Internal code as well, use OpenFileDialog and your code will crash.  You can always get a full path with Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location and the Path class:

```
var exedir = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var path = Path.Combine(exedir, @"Config\launcher.txt");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path)) {
    //...
}
```

Now it always works.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your path is relative and the Current Working Directory is different when the console app kicks off your winform. Also, you should wrap the stream reader in a `using` statement. As it stands, unless you explicitly call `Dispose()` elsewhere in your code you're holding on to resources that should be freed.

To fix your problem either change the `WorkingDirectory` when you start the process using `Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` or change the path in your code so it is not relative. Or another option would be to pass the path to the application or read it from a resource file so that it can be given the appropriate path when it executes.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in the question. you are saying that "When I run it with console application, which is not in the same directory". if it's not in the same directory how will it find a directory "Config" if it diesn't exist there. make sure that the directory exist there