# streamreader paths to file

Tags: c#, delphi, filepath, streamreader

While in a search to learn more about the streamreader, i came across this from
[StreamReader path changes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930475/streamreader-path-changes-automatically)
post #2 by

> Hans Passant

```
var exedir = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var path = Path.Combine(exedir, @"Config\launcher.txt"); using (var
reader = new StreamReader(path)) {
    //... }
```

Now I understand the "never hard code the file" part, In delphi, I am able to specify a custom file path based on the files in a directory ie.

Read all file names in a directory, user chooses a file name, and then I read the contents of the file

Delphi, I just used a string and added the file name to the end, how does that differ from the code above, and is there a different method to this above?

and btw. Could someone just explain in a bit more detail, the methods and variables used and why (i am still new to c#)

Comment: I've edited your question. Focus on your problem, don't add unnecessary information which diverts from topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Hans is saying here is that if you are expecting the files to be relative to your application code, then **expliclty look relative to your application code**. Don't rely on the current directory being the base location of your application, as that is not guaranteed (and can change during your application's execution). So what the code does is:

- obtain the entry-point assembly (the assembly with the `Main` method that was executed at startup), and obtion the file location of that assembly: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`
- obtain the directory from this file path: `var exedir = Path.GetDirectory(...);`
- construct a path relative to this directory: `var path = Path.Combine(exedir, @"Config\launcher.txt");`
- create a reader based on the final path: `using (var
  reader = new StreamReader(path)) ...`

Answer (score 0):

GetEntryAssembly returns, according to the documentation:

> The assembly that is the process executable in the default
>   application domain, or the first executable that was
>   executed by AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly.

And the Location property returns the full path of the assembly. So

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

is the full path of the executable. In Delphi you would write ParamStr(0) or Application.ExeFileName.

Path.GetDirectory strips off the file name and leaves the directory. In Delphi you'd use ExtractFilePath.

And Path.Combine simple joins two path components, adding a path separator if necessary. In Delphi you'd use TPath.Combine from the IOUtils unit.

So the code in the question constructs the full path to a file named

```
<exedir>\Config\launcher.txt
```

where  is the directory containing the main executable assembly which is of course known only at runtime.

There's really nothing particularly different between the way things are done in Delphi and C#. To construct the same path in either language you take the exact same steps modulo syntax/method name differences.

Possibly you are in the habit of assuming that the working directory is the directory containing the executable assembly. If so, lose that habit. The working directory is meaningful for a console application and for such an application it can be considered an input to the program. But don't expect it to be stable in a GUI program. And never assume that the working directory contains the executable. That assumption is not valid.

On the other hand, perhaps you really do want a path relative to the working directory. In which case simply supply the filename and let the system take care of the rest.